# ¿Cómo puedo agregarle estilos a ciertos hijos?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy practicando HTML y CSS; me encontré un ejercicio que era posicionar unas imágenes en distintos puntos, como in zig zag (imagen de referencia):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que se puede hacer con `nth-child`, pero al usarlo, o no me agrega el estilo, o lo pone a todos:

```css
.containerPhotos {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.containerPhotos .photoBox {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 410px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 50px;
}

.containerPhotos .photoBox:nth-child(1) {
  margin: 200px 50px;
}

.containerPhotos .photoBox::before {
  content: attr(data-name);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.containerPhotos .photoBox::after {
  content: attr(data-job);
  position: absolute;
  right: -35%;
  top: 18%;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

.containerPhotos .photoBox img {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 410px;
}
```

```html
<section class="containerPhotos">
  <div class="photoBox" data-name="Bill Mahoney" data-job="product owner">
    <img src="./assets/images/team/photo1.png" alt="Bill Mahoney">
  </div>
  <div class="photoBox" data-name="Saba Cabrera" data-job="art director">
    <img src="./assets/images/team/photo2.png" alt="Saba Cabrera">
  </div>
</section>
```

No sé porqué no me toma los hijos correctos. Lo he intentado de muchas formas. Agradecería la ayuda. Y de ser posible, si me pueden ayudar a validar el responsive. Pero la primera cuestión me es más importante.

Comment: ¿Ya has intentado hacer un div para cada columna? Pudieras tener un div que abarque las 3, y luego dentro tener un div para cada columna, ya que las tienes todas en línea, solamente al div de en medio le puedes aplicar un margin-top, de esta manera puedes crear el efecto de zig-zag. Otro acercamiento sería usar CSS Grid.

Comment: Es que no sé cómo diseñar una grid con css puro.

Comment: Claro que sí. Me interesa aprender de grid. Aunque ya resolvieron el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo simplificado que hace lo que mencionas. `nth-child(even)` aplica un `margin-top` a todos los elementos pares.

```css
.containerPhotos{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.photoBox:nth-child(even){
  margin-top:60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="containerPhotos">
  <div class="photoBox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png" alt="Bill Mahoney">
  </div>
  <div class="photoBox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png" alt="Saba Cabrera">
  </div>
   <div class="photoBox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png" alt="Saba Cabrera">
  </div>

</section>

<section class="containerPhotos">
  <div class="photoBox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png" alt="Bill Mahoney">
  </div>
  <div class="photoBox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png" alt="Saba Cabrera">
  </div>
   <div class="photoBox">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png" alt="Saba Cabrera">
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. ¿Por qué el even funciona de esa manera?

Comment: Eso una instrucción de css even(par) y odd(impar) . Puedes leer más aquí https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp